# I am unable to create a new account in my app. Create account button does nothing

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to go through the signup procedure for my app, but when I hit create account, it doesn't do anything. It just remains on the same page. The create account button should fire the following method:

```
@IBAction func createAccountPress(_ sender: Any){

        guard usernameField.text != "", emailField_SU.text != "", passwordField_SU.text != "", confirmPasswordField_SU.text != "" else {return}

        if passwordField_SU == confirmPasswordField_SU{
            if let email = emailField_SU.text, let password = passwordField_SU.text{
                Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
                { (user,error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    if let user = user {
                        let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser!.createProfileChangeRequest()
                        changeRequest.displayName = self.usernameField.text
                        changeRequest.commitChanges(completion:nil)
                        let imageRef = self.userStorage.child("\(user.user.uid).jpg")
                        let data = self.userImgView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality:0.5)

                        let uploadTask = imageRef.putData(data!, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata,error) in
                            if error != nil{
                                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                            }
                            imageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                                }
                                if let url = url {
                                    let userInfo: [String:Any] = ["uid": user.user.uid,
                                                                  "username": self.usernameField.text!,
                                                                  "urlToImage":url.absoluteString]

                                    self.ref.child("users").child(user.user.uid).setValue(userInfo)
                                    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"signinVC")
                                    self.present(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
                                }
                            })
                    })
                    uploadTask.resume()
                        //self.storeUserData(userId: (user.user.uid))
                        //KeychainWrapper.standard.set((user.user.uid), forKey:"uid")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"backToSignin", sender: nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Password does not match")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting any errors thrown at all, and the app isn't exiting at all either. It just doesn't do anything, when at the very least the app should segue back to the sign in view. Do you see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you used the debugger and traced through this code? What does it actually do? Where does is go wrong?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to debug in Xcode, but I figured that out. It's saying the passwords are not the same when the passwords are in fact the same. It's not going to the else statement however which is odd.

Comment: `if passwordField_SU == confirmPasswordField_SU` is comparing the actual text fields, not the text inside them

Comment: following @dan's comment try replacing `if passwordField_SU == confirmPasswordField_SU` with `if passwordField_SU.text == confirmPasswordField_SU.text`. I would also add some breakpoints to see what's happening: quick/easy way is to click the line number to add the breakpoint and right click the line number to disable/delete it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of redudent code there but I think this maybe part of the issue

```
if passwordField_SU == confirmPasswordField_SU
```

as that code is verifying if the password *field* is the same as the confirm password *field* which they aren't because they are two different fields.

You are probably trying to confirm the user entered the same password twice and they are not empty

```
if passwordField_SU.text == confirmPasswordField_SU.text {
```

etc